# How to reconnect chromecast device when restart app in android

Tags: android, chromecast

Hello  every one i faced one problem regarding chromecast when i connect to chromecast device and remove app from background and after that again open app 
but app disconnect  to chromecast device can any idea to auto connect chromecast device to my app please suggest .

Answer (score 0):

You can follow our [documentation](https://developers.google.com/cast/docs/reconnection) on this very subject, if yo want to do it yourself, or you can use [Cast Companion Library](https://github.com/googlecast/CastCompanionLibrary-android) that does it for you. In short, you need to persist a few pieces of data (such as session id, route id) and use them to perform reconnection.